# APE/Phangorn: how to wrap tip labels?

Tags: r, phylogeny, r-ape

I'm using `ape::plot.phylo` (called via `phangorn::plotBS`?) to plot some phylogenetic trees. The problem is that the tip labels are quite long, and I'd like to have them wrap around somehow. I can't seem to find any options within `plot` or `plot.phylo`/`plotBS` to take care of this.

Any ideas how I can get the `tip.labels` to be text-wrapped?

Sample tip label: "QER Echinodermata Asterozoa Asteroidea Forcipulatacea Forcipulatida Asteriidae Asterias Asterias.rubens UNID1"

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be indeed to change the `tip.label` element in the `phylo` object.

```
## Making a tree with three tips of 20 characters each
tree <- rcoal(3, tip.label = replicate(3, paste(sample(letters, 20), collapse = "")))
## The tree tip labels
tree$tip.label
# [1] "thsdmrigufpykvlawqbz" "dlicefyjonmqugbptxzr" "adioznspgbkjqryelfum"
```

You can then wrap around every nth character by a new line character (`\n`) as follows:

```
## Declaring the pattern and text to replace at a specific position
position <- 10
pattern <- paste0('^([a-z]{', position-1, '})([a-z]+)$')
text <- paste0('\\1', "\n", '\\2')
wrap_tips <- gsub(pattern, text, tree$tip.label)
wrap_tips
# [1] "thsdmrigu\nfpykvlawqbz" "dlicefyjo\nnmqugbptxzr" "adioznspg\nbkjqryelfum"
```

Of course you can also replace a specific character (like `_` or `.`) by `\n` which is more simple (e.g. `gsub("_", "\\n", tree$tip.label)`).

You can then create a copy of the tree and give it the wrapped tip labels:

```
## Duplicating the tree
tree_to_plot <- tree
## Changing the labels
tree_to_plot$tip.label <- wrap_tips
## Plotting the wrapped labels
plot(tree_to_plot)
```